# How to install TCPDF to symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, tcpdf

I want generata PDF file by symfony 2, so I use

> composer require tecnick.com/tcpdf

It created new folder name tecnick.com/tcpdf in my Vendors folder
So how I call tcpdf class?

Comment: look for online documentations

Comment: I read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html but tecnick does not create bundle

Answer (score 2):

This bundle uses the last version of TCPDF from the [official website](http://www.tcpdf.org). The installation as Symfony bundle is different (from the regular installation) because you're using it with the Symfony framework. In this case you won't be using `require_once` etc. because Symfony does that for you.

For general information, consider [reading the official bundle documentation](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle)

First add this to the `require` section of your projects `composer.json`

```
"whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Then execute `composer install`.

When is finished, register the bundle in the `app/AppKernel.php`:

```
<?php

 public function registerBundles()
 {
     $bundles = array(
      // ...
         new WhiteOctober\TCPDFBundle\WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle(),
      );
 }
```

Now you can use TCPDF on your controllers, for example:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    ...

    public function mypdfAction(Request $request){

        $pdf = $this->container->get("white_october.tcpdf")->create(
            'LANDSCAPE',
            PDF_UNIT,
            PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,
            true,
            'UTF-8',
            false
        );
        $pdf->SetAuthor('qweqwe');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Prueba TCPDF');
        $pdf->SetSubject('Your client');
        $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
        $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11, '', true);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $html = '<h1>Working on Symfony</h1>';

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(
            $w = 0,
            $h = 0,
            $x = '',
            $y = '',
            $html,
            $border = 0,
            $ln = 1,
            $fill = 0,
            $reseth = true,
            $align = '',
            $autopadding = true
        );

        $pdf->Output("example.pdf", 'I');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for this available : [TCPDF](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle)

Comment: but I want to use tecnick